# perl script to read xml file and create a property file

Tags: perl

Perl script to read property.xml and create install.properties file

how to read multiple lines and split keyName and keyValue

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', "property.xml"  or die "property.xml: $!";
open(CTS,">install.properties") or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

if ($line =~ m/\<entry.*\<\/entry\>$/i ){     # how to read multiple line
my ($keyName, $keyValue) = split(//, $line);     # how to split 
print CTS $keyName = $keyValue;
}
}
```

property.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="TYPE">
    Rel
    </entry>
    <!-- tst  -->
    <entry key="LOCATION">
    C:/Rel-LOCATION
    </entry>
    <entry key="HOST">
    localhost
    </entry>    
</properties>
```

install.properties

```
TYPE = Rel
LOCATION = C:/Rel-LOCATION
HOST = localhost
```

Comment: So what's the question..?

Comment: 1. That isn't XML, it would have a root element otherwise. 2. Just use an XML parser like [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) and extract your information via XPath expressions. Come back if you have problems with that.

Comment: Re: your updated question. Your problem *could* be solved by using regexes, but this is really poor style and is difficult to do correctly. Please, **use an XML parser**. This is really not hard, and can be done in less lines than your current code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the code somewhat like this, using XML::LibXML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::LibXML;

# Parse the XML
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'test.xml');

# Iterate the entries
for my $entry ($xml->findnodes('/properties/entry')) {

    my $key = $entry->findvalue('@key');

    # trim the value
    s/\A\s*//, s/\s*\z// for my $value = $entry->textContent;

    say "$key = $value";
}
```

The statement `s/\A\s*//, s/\s*\z// for my $value = $entry->textContent` is a shorthand for

```
my $value = $entry->textContent;
$value =~ s/\A\s*//;
$value =~ s/\s*\z//;
```

The substitutions do the trimming; `\A` anchores at the start of string, `\z` at the end (and are roughly equivalent to `^` and `$` resp.).

The `say` feature is available since perl5 v10, and offers the `say` function which works like `print`, but appends a newline.

Simple XPath expressions work just like file paths, but `@key` selects an attribute.

The various DOM node methods I used here are:

- `findnodes` – get a list of nodes that match the XPath expression.
- `findvalue` – get a node that matches the XPath, and return the text value.
- `textContent` – return the value of the text node.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do this using XML::Twig, with a few modern idioms thrown in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open); # dies with error message when open fails

use XML::Twig;

my $IN= "properties.xml";
my $OUT= "install.properties";

open( my $cts, '>', $OUT); # avoid "bareword filehandles" (CTS), use 3 arg open

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { entry => \&entry, },)
         ->parsefile( $IN);

sub entry
  { my( $t, $entry)= @_;
    print {$cts} $entry->att( 'key'), " = ", $entry->trimmed_text, "\n"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) my all time favorite "XML parser" for simple XML processing. It loads your file into a ready to use perl hash/array of hash/array of ... :-

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = XMLin('test.xml'); # load the file
print STDERR Dumper($ref);   # see how it looks
foreach my $k (keys %{$ref->{entry}}) # output to conf
{
    $v = $ref->{entry}->{$k}->{content};
    print "$k=$v\n";
}
```

Works nicely :-

```
% perl test.pl

HOST=
    localhost

LOCATION=
    C:\Rel-LOCATION

TYPE=
    Rel
```

I have left the trimming etc for you :)

Comment: [XML::Simple is deprecated in favour of XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#STATUS_OF_THIS_MODULE), according to its own docs. (While it is extremely DWIM in cases like this, it is extremely difficult to use for general problems).

Comment: I didn't know that. Nevertheless I'll let the answer stay to hopefully improve my rep :) and less importantly because that's what I'd do even today instead of using a full-fledged xml parser

Comment: its failing with msg
junk after document element at line 3, column 0, byte 44 at C:/Perl64/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187
in parser.pm

186  eval {
187    $result = $expat->parse($arg);
188  };

Comment: issue was with xml file format, its working fine.
many thanks Himanshu